# oauth20 is working properly but passport local not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth-2.0, session-cookies, passport-local

this is my local strategy configuration

```
const passport = require('passport')
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
const LocalUsers = require('../db/localUser')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')


passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password'
},
    (username, password, done) => {
        LocalUsers.findOne({ email: username }, async (err, user) => {
            
            if (err) { return done(err); }
            if (!user) {
                return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect email.' });
            }
            const matchedPassword = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
            if (!matchedPassword) {
                return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
            }
            else{
                return done(null, user);
            }
            
        });
    }
));

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    return done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
    await LocalUsers.findById(id, function (err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});
```

and this is the server file

```
require('dotenv').config()

const express = require('express')
const app = express()

const authRoute = require('./routes/auth')
const loginRoute = require('./routes/login')
const homeRoute = require('./routes/home')
const signupRoute = require('./routes/signup')

const passport = require('passport')
const session = require('express-session')
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')

require('./db/connection')

require('./config/local-passport-setup')
require('./config/google-passport-setup')

const store = MongoStore.create({ mongoUrl: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/quora', collectionName: 'sessions' })

app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

app.use(session({
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    secret:'qwerty',
    store: store,
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
    }
}))

app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())

app.set('view engine', 'hbs')

app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    if (!req.user) {
        res.redirect('/login')
    }
    else {
        res.redirect('/home')
    }
})

app.use('/', homeRoute)
app.use('/login', loginRoute)
app.use('/auth', authRoute)
app.use('/', signupRoute)

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('server started on http://localhost:3000')
})
```

here I am calling the passport.authenticate function

```
onst express = require('express')
const route = express.Router()

const passport = require('passport')
require('../config/local-passport-setup')

route.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('login')
})

route.post('/', passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/home', failureRedirect: '/login' }))

module.exports = route
```

here the serialize user and deserialize user functions are never being called and thus the req.user is undefined

here the user is not getting authenticated although this oAuth code is working properly

```
const passport = require('passport')
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy
const GoogleUsers = require('../db/googleUser')

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy(
    {
        clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/google/redirect'
    },
    (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
        GoogleUsers.findOne({ googleId: profile.id })
            .then((currentUser) => {
                if (currentUser) {
                    console.log('current user: ', currentUser)
                    done(null, currentUser)
                }
                else {
                    const newUser = new GoogleUsers({
                        googleId: profile.id,
                        name: profile.displayName
                    })
                    newUser.save()
                        .then((newUser) => {
                            console.log('new user: ', newUser)
                            done(null, newUser)
                        })
                }
            })
    }
))

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
    await GoogleUsers.findById(id, function (err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});
```

Please help me out I have been figuring out the error for a lot time now

Comment: Could you paste your code where you're calling passport.authenticate()?

Comment: Please include the error text to help others help you out.

Comment: @IAmDranged I have edited the question and included the code where I am calling passport.authenticate().

Comment: I don't see anything blatantly wrong. I actually tested the code successfully on my side - I did comment out and adjust a couple things though just to make it work with my particular setup. What happens exactly when you try to login? Are you being redirected to the success or failure endpoint? Are you having an error? Please include a bit more details in your post about what actually happens.

Comment: When I try to login with the correct credentials it redirects to the success endpoint and with the wrong credentials it redirects to the failure endpoint. But the user is not getting serialized and not getting stored in session

Comment: You're using a browser to navigate the site? Have you tried removing the "store: store" session option, and giving it a go like that - the session will just be kept in memory that way.